# YouTube API: Search: List from the Data API always returns around 6k videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Thanks for the help in advance. I couldn't find anything about what I'm seeing in the API docs or on StackOverflow.

I'm seeing very strange behavior from the *Search* API. I always get around 6000 results, regardless of the request.

Is this expected?

How can I get the actual number of videos that match the search?

---

For example:

The following request of live videos and no other query parameters:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&eventType=live&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

Returns 5915 videos:

```
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5915,
}
```

But, a request of live videos in the US and under the gaming category: (a more narrow search)

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&eventType=live&regionCode=US&type=video&videoCategoryId=20&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

Returns 5970 videos:

```
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5970
}
```

Somehow **more** videos than the more general search.

Answer (score -1):

YouTube is a very complex system. I like to think that over time I have gotten a pretty good understanding on how some aspects of it work, but I wouldn't pretend to know the entirety of how the system operates.

For all I know, there might be tens or hundreds of thousands of live streams at any given time. Maybe capping the search results at 6k is just YouTube's way of dealing with the vast amount of data they have to go through for every search request while still trying to give you the most relevant information.

Take this query, for example, which searches for basically every video:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

which returns

```
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
```

Given that the total amount of videos on YouTube is estimated to be in the multi-billions, one million seems to be a pretty low number here. So, yeah, I think this behaviour is to be expected.